# Use cell color as a condition in VB.NET IF statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, for-loop, datagridview

I am currently working in Visual Studio Express 2013. I have often changed the colors of cells based on an IF statement to represent the data but now i am trying to run code based on a cell color.I am having a hard time figuring this one out. The DGV I am using is link to an SQL back end. Here is what I am trying:

```
   Dim max As Integer = DGVJobs.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim total As String = "------>"
            Dim AssemHoursTotal As Integer = 0
            Dim BodyHoursTotal As Integer = 0

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVJobs.Rows
                If Not .rows(row).cells("AssemHours").defaultcellstyle.backcolor = Color.Orange = True Then
                    AssemHoursTotal += row.Cells("AssemHours").Value
                    BodyHoursTotal += row.Cells("BodyHours").Value
                End If

            Next
            MsgBox(AssemHoursTotal)
            MsgBox(BodyHoursTotal)
```

My error occurs on the line where "If Not .Rows.....". I need to loop through these 2 columns to sum the contents but not include any rows with an orange back color.

Comment: Why not use the data/condition used in the IF statement used to set the color?  If need be, you could use an invisible column to store the result

Comment: I thought about that, but, due to the process for which I am building this code, I can not do this. I am using this in a production process and the reason the code is orange could change within the time I need this code to run. Therefore I have to do it from the DGV. I wish I could explain this in more detail here but it would take 3 pages of explanations, as well as company information im not willing to divulge on the internet. Sorry.

Comment: No.  Rather than *just* paint something orange, store the result in an invisible DGV column then use *that* to a) paint in orange AndAlso b) in the If statement to do something Special work from that invisible column which will be as static as the color.  It would work even if the DGV is bound

Comment: alright let me put some thought into it for a min.

Comment: You could use the cells tag object as well...